UTM parameters doesn't work with Elementor Mega Menu
My website WordPress website doesn't gather UTM parameters when I navigate the links with the mega menu. but the main navigation and the other links / buttons work fine and gathering all UTM parameters. The plugin I use for UTM gathering is: HandL UTM Grabber and I have checked - Append UTM variables to all the links automatically option on the plugin. Page Builder has been used to build the site: Elementor Pro. Also I noticed that clicking the logo doesn't append UTMs either.
I also checked the plugin's documentation which says if I add this custom attribute: class|utm-out it will be working fine but unfortunately No! its not client/server side cache either. What could be the best way to solve this?
Thanks.
